# How to attach something to textarea value after foreach (PHP)

Tags: php

Okay, try to explain. I have a table:

```
<tr>
<td>Some specific question 1</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="v29" value="Some specific question: standart answer 1" checked="" >Standart answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="v29" value="Some specific question: standart answer 2">Standart answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="v29">or print your answer<br>
<textarea name="v29" cols="50" placeholder="Enter text here" ></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Some specific question 2</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="v30" value="Some specific question: standart answer 1" checked="" >Standart answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="v30" value="Some specific question: standart answer 2">Standart answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="v30">or print your answer<br>
<textarea name="v30" cols="50" placeholder="Enter text here" ></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Some specific question 3</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="v31" value="Some specific question: standart answer 1" checked="" >Standart answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="v31" value="Some specific question: standart answer 2">Standart answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="v31">or print your answer<br>
<textarea name="v31" cols="50" placeholder="Enter text here" ></textarea></td>
</tr>
<input type="submit" name="submitgop" style="margin-right:7px;  margin-left:7px;" value="Save">
```

"submitgop" button starts this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $answerText[$i] = $value;
    $i++;
}
```

First two buttons will return perfect "Question: answer" pair from table. But when user is choose third button, it'll return only "answer". I want to fix it, and somehow add "Question: " to the value of third button (which is textarea).

Comment: I think you'll need to show more code than that. What does the form HTML look like? Tough to know what's going on here?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please try to explain the background better. Exactly what you're trying to do, and where's the problem.

Comment: Edited first post. Maybe it will be more detailed now.

Comment: each name needs to be unique, you have three "v29"

Comment: It's not the problem.

Comment: Really bad English is provided! Can you exactly mention what do you want to do?

Comment: Tried to explain it once more, psot edited.

Comment: I wouldn't have the question and the answer inside the value of  your inputs, I would define an array with the questions and then link them while looping through $_POST